# PowerPoint record slide show function accessible through Interop with C#

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint

I am currently trying to write an addin for PowerPoint that whenever any PowerPoint document is opened and then run in show mode that the feature to record narration audio and slide timings is automatically activated.

However I cannot seem to find that option in the PowerPoint interop object

The manual in application way to use this feature in Powerpoint 2007 is under the "Slide Show" tab of the ribbon called "Record Narration".

I have found under that I can set under Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SlideShowSettings.AdvancedSettings to RehearseNewTimings but this does not record narration audio.

Does anyone know if this is even possible? Or if I am completely on the wrong track here.

Thanks in advance for any repsonse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you record a macro of this record operation to do the same thing?

As I discuss on my blog entitled, [Tribal Knowledge: Working with Office Interops](http://www.omegacoder.com/?p=72), one way to divine the inner workings of any office document and how to manage it via the interops is to record a macro of the process needed. Once done examine the vba code, it will show settings changes and other items of interest that can lead the way through the tribal knowledge of the interops. Most the object calls are the same under the covers...good luck.
Otherwise if try this question in the forums of [Discussions in Office Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/newsgroups/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.officedev&lang=en&cr=US) or [Discussions in Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/newsgroups/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.office.developer.automation&lang=en&cr=US) which is a good one for interop questions.
HTH

Comment: Thanks OmegaMan

Great suggestion however when I recorded the macro it does not seem to account for the recording of the sound and timings i.e. when I go to run the macro it does not re-record the sound and timings but just replays the already recorded content.

Oh well I am starting to think that this feature is not available through the Office Interop, I will have to code something that replicates the same functionality.

Thanks again